# MySQL Connect, XAMPP and ODBC

Tags: python, mysql, xampp

Note:**I am connecting using Python2.7 in a virtualenv to access MySQL on XAMPP, which was not installed on the virtualenv.

I am trying to connect with MySQL via python. I recently downloaded MySQL connect from Oracle. I also downloaded the ODBC driver from the same site. When I plug in the information below, I get a 2003 error telling me that it cannot connect:

> mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'

but when I include the port number in my connection, it freezes up and nothing happens.

This is my code:

```
>>>import mysql.connector
>>>cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='[my username]',password='[my password]',host='127.0.0.1', database='FXPrices',port=80)
```

After that, the cursor indents--so there are no arrows for the python prompt. I have to hit control-z every time I want it to stop. Do I need mod_wsgi to fix this?

Comment: Thanks, Mata. I tried port 3306, but it keeps giving me the same InterfaceError:2003. Oh, I need to edit the post. I'm doing this over virtualenv on my python environment, XAMPP was not in the virtualenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to connect to the http port (port 80) on your machine.

MySQL by default listens to port 3306, you shoud try that (it's the same if you omit the `port` argument), or try to find out on which port your mysql server is really listening.

Comment: port 80 stalls, but port 3306 produces the same 2003 error. When I omit the port, the 2003 error is also raised.

Comment: are you sure the mysql server is running? Which OS are you using? Maybe the server is configured only to listen to a unix domain socket, try removing both the host/port arguments...

Comment: I'm using Mac OSX Lion 10.7.5. I omitted the host and port but got the same error. I checked my mysqld file and showed that it's pointing to port 0, but my .cnf file is showing that the port is 3306. Could this be the discrepancy?

Comment: `sudo netstat -lpn | grep mysqld` should show you what mysqld is listening on, maybe that helps you.

Comment: [Resolved]: I retried this evening. I'm not sure if I will be able to recreate this, but I searched for the mysqld executable using the Mac finder and clicked on it to activate. When I reran the code, the connection didn't throw back any errors in my try/except statement! I do notice that, after I close the extra terminal window from selecting mysqld, the XAMPP MySQL server keeps throwing an error saying that another server is running, so I just need to kill the process in the terminal (I restarted my computer & it worked again). Thanks for all your help!